# Where do you put _app.js in the app directory

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth, next.js13

Documentation for next-auth (version 4) indicates that we need to put the service provider in:

```
pages/_app.js
```

I am following the example:
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example

If I'm using the experimental app directory instead of the pages directory in nextjs 13, where do we put that _app.js file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to have two implementations.

In experimental app directory you have to wrap root layout.

```
// app/provider.js

"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Proiders({ children }) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

then in root layout

```
import Provider from "./provider";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <Provider>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

similarly you have to wrap `_app.js` too

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

api file is the same directory. `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

Comment: Thank you.  Example on how to put it in the root layout in the app folder worked for me.